# How to make multiple commands executed sequentially in atd

Tags: linux, bash

```
echo "echo `date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'`'  hello' >> tmp.log;
      sleep 3s;
      echo `date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'`'  world' >> tmp.log" |
at now
```

I hope that these 3 commands will be executed in sequence use atd, but it is counterproductive. The 3 commands are executed in parallel. How can I execute these 3 commands in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atd` does run commands sequentially, the problem is that `both date commands` run at the time you submit the job due to expansion, try :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S hello"  > /tmp/at.log;
      sleep 3s;
      date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S world" >> /tmp/at.log' |
at now
```